# Why did god create humans according to hinduism?

Tags: creation

What the reason god thought, for creating humans. I mean here was no requirement for god to create humans. God could have created just microrganism plants and few animals.

But why did god create humans. There was nothing mandatory for god to create humans.

God could have just stoped after creating microrganism, but god proceds furthure to create humans.

Why was this thing to create humans necessary for god?

Comment: In 9 types of Lord Brahma's creation, human beings' creation comes at 7th...Lord Brahma wanted to create some beings of middle quality after creating the deities of Satva quality....

Comment: "There was nothing mandatory for god to create humans." We all have dharmic roles to play, so we are necessary. Else, who or what would fill our roles?

Comment: **With a view to the development (for the sake of the prosperity) of the [three] regions [lokā / worlds]**, He brought into existence the Brāhmaṇa, the Kṣatriya, the Vaiśya and the Śūdra [collectively humans], from out of His mouth, arms, thighs and feet [respectively]. ~ *Manusmriti 1.31*